# tableview NSInvalidArgumentException and i don't know why

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to make a table view using the following array and objects.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    characterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    character * Choice = [[character alloc] init];

    Choice.name = @"creat new character";
    [characterArray addObject:Choice];

    character * secondChoice = [[character alloc]init];
    secondChoice.name = @"paliden";
    [characterArray addObject:secondChoice];
}
```

But i keep getting `NSInvalidArgumentException`, reason: `-[character isEqualToString:]`

I've figured out that the problem is here in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
cell.textLabel.text = [characterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong, and until i made a few changes to the array, the code was working fine. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: in cellForRowAtIndexPath again u have to get the name so create Character *choice=(Character *)[characterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  then cell.textLabel.text =choice.name; try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should provide a String as the text of the cell.textLabel.text. In your code, you just gives your object to the cell.textLabel.text which is incorrect. cast the [characterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] to (character *) then call .name, that will return a String. give that string as the input of cell.textLabel.text

try this,

```
cell.textLabel.text = ((character *)[characterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).name;
```

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath to get the name from character create

`Character *choice=(Character *)[characterArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`
 then

`cell.textLabel.text =choice.name;`

try this hope will help